# codename one RPC library with springboot server

Tags: spring-boot, codenameone

I have an existing SpringBoot server in which i would like to add the CN1RPC library and make webservice for the client app.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codename1</groupId>
    <artifactId>cn1rpc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

The Maven dependency does not seem to work, as directed from [this github post](https://github.com/shannah/CN1RPC#installation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That artifact isn’t on Maven Central.  You need to do the first step of cloning it and running mvn install to add it locally.